# How does php refer to the current document?

Tags: php, document

My webpage allows users to select items from a dropdown list and has a table. Javascript prints out each dropdown-list-item (plus extra info that javascript pulls from the XML file) in a new table row that javascript creates.

I want to be able to write the table information to disk.
If I was using Javascript, I would use document.getElementByID("table") to parse through the nodes and put that info into variables that I could write.  However, most documentation I find says Javascript is not used for writing to disk.  So, I think I should use php.

What is the php equivalent of Javascript's 'document' object?
In Javascript I don't need to define any new objects to use it, I can use 'document' anytime.
I think in php I have to use new DOMDocument. and then load the html.

Most of the php examples show loadHTML(string) and loadHTMLFile();
I don't want to load HTML from a string that I write inside the  tags.
And I don't want to load HTML from the .htm file because that's the original file and Javascript has changed the user's file based on their selections from the dropdown menu.

I want to access the elements of the current document using php.
So, how does php refer to the current document?

The page I'm working on is http://music.collwyncraig.info/hajimama/setlist.htm

Comment: PHP does *not* run in the browser.  It often runs in webservers, or as standalone programs.  If some PHP program can obtain the webpage, it can parse it and write it to disk, but that would have nothing to do with running from within a browser.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand that.  So, what can I use to obtain the information from the page (the HTML DOM) running in the browser and send it back to the server so that I can save it in a file on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your thoughts about the architecture are wrong. There is a way how the programming languages interact with each other.

- php is a preprocessor and generates - what ever u want - usually html, containing javascript, css, and whatever...
- javascript is a dynamic language that interacts in the generated html documents or calls by ajax other services that deliver html, javascript, css or whatever is needed
- and html - that is document object that is displayed and can be modified during the runtime by javascript an styled by css, etc...

So when u call in your documents javascript functions - the basic php has already done its job.

Instead of printing all generated contents from php directly to the screen, you can store it first in a var.

For example:

```
$myContent = "<html><head>...</head><body><h1>Whatever...</h1></body>";
```

so with that you can do the following to print it on the screen:

```
print "myContent";  // and it is shown on the screen
```

or

```
$myFile = "testFile.html";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$myContent = "<html><head>...</head><body><h1>Whatever...</h1></body>";
fwrite($fh, $myContent);
$myContent = "Whatever2";
fwrite($fh, $myContent);
fclose($fh);
```

So the contents of your file would be:

```
<html><head>...</head><body><h1>Whatever...</h1></body>Whatever2
```

This generated document can then be called by `loadHTML` or used in which way you
 want.

This just as a hint into which direction you can think - there are quite multiple ways of solution - so without knowing more about what u really want - it is quite not easy to mention a proper solution.

Comment: Thanks. Currently, a user is able to build a table on my webpage by selecting items from a dropdown menu.  Javascript builds this table based on their choices from the dropdown menu.  I want to have a button the user can click to Save their created table into a file.

So I need to access the DOM of the current page in the browser, and send it back to the server and write it in a file. Right?

I can use Javascript to access the current page's DOM in the browser.  and I can use php to write something into a file on the server.  I don't know how to connect these two actions.

Comment: You want to store it on the server ? Well - if u can access the document - so just send the contents of it to a php file by parameter that store it like mentioned above. $mycontent = $_POST['theDocument'] - can be called by javascript by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` for the main file.

or

`__FILE__` for the full path to the file where this was called.

PHP doesn't have any builtin' DOM Manipulator like jQuery - html output is usually generated through some template engine of your choice or manually.
If you want DOM manipulation like jQuery, you might want to try out PHPQuery

http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/